# jqgrid edit cell trigger on lost focus

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using cell edit on editing in jqgrid.

I'm trying to set status editing = true when user start to editing some cell on beforeeditcell and editing = false when user leave the textbox.

```
beforeEditCell : function(rowid, iRow, iCol){
                    selICol = iCol;
                    selIRow = iRow;
                    editingstatus = true;
                },
```

and i want to set editing status back to false

```
beforeSaveCell : function(){
                    editingstatus=false;
                },
```

but if user didnt change data .. it seems that beforesavecell is not triggered and editingstatus still true. What is more appropriate trigger than beforesavecell event users didnt change the data... TIA

Comment: im using both afterRestoreCell and afterSaveCell. works fine

Answer (score 1):

Try **afterEditCell** event:

```
afterEditCell: function(){
                    editingstatus=false;
                },
```